# STM32H7 LTDC LCD MIPI DBI

Tags: stm32, lcd, ltdc

I am using STM32H723ZG with LCD controller ILI9488 working with MIPI DBI type B interface (16 data lines).

Interface pins on the LCD controller are:

CS(Chip Select), DC(Data/Command), RD(Read signal), WR (Write signal).
ST LTDC peripheral does not have DC, RD.

1. Can LTDC CLK be configured to act as WR?
2. How can I control the number of bytes being sent via LTDC (how to control the number of clocks in the CLK signal)?
3. Can I send Commands to the LCD controller (ILI9488) using ST LTDC? If yes, how can I sync between the DC (GPIO) and WR (LTDC?)?

Comment: The LTDC module in your STM32 is for 'dumb' displays which don't have their own internal controller & RAM. Since your display has an ILI9488 controller, it's a 'smart' display and does also have its own RAM. You should interface it to your STM32's FMC peripheral (probably using its NOR Flash/PSRAM mode), not the LTDC.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand that point. But is it possible to use LTDC and DBI type B? and in LTDC application they so a scheme of using FMC when using LTDC.

Comment: Ad you've already discovered, the LTDC does not have the signals you're looking for (and I'm not aware of any sensible way to fake them through the LTDC). I'm not sure which LTDC application you're referring to, but based on my experience with the STM32H743 Eval board and a custom STM32H750-based device I think it's likely that the FMC in that application is being used to interface with an external RAM which is being used as the framebuffer for a 'dumb' TFT LCD connected to the LTDC (not a 'smart' device like your ILI9488 based display).

Comment: https://fastbitlab.com/display-interface-types/ is helpful understanding why LTDC is used to interface to MIPI DPI but NOT to MIPI DBI.

Comment: Thank you all !